# SQL PROJECT Karaokw Song

Tags: mysql

Question:-Maybe your friends only like singing either recent songs or truly epic songs. Add another SELECT that uses OR to show the titles of the songs that have an 'epic' mood or a release date after 1990.

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    artist TEXT,
    mood TEXT,
    duration INTEGER,
    released INTEGER);


INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("Bohemian Rhapsody", "Queen", "epic", 60, 1975);
INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("Let it go", "Idina Menzel", "epic", 227, 2013);
INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("I will survive", "Gloria Gaynor", "epic", 198, 1978);
INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("Twist and Shout", "The Beatles", "happy", 152, 1963);
INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("La Bamba", "Ritchie Valens", "happy", 166, 1958);
INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("I will always love you", "Whitney Houston", "epic", 273, 1992);
INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("Sweet Caroline", "Neil Diamond", "happy", 201, 1969);
INSERT INTO songs (title, artist, mood, duration, released)
    VALUES ("Call me maybe", "Carly Rae Jepsen", "happy", 193, 2011);


Select title FROM songs;

Select title FROM songs where mood ="Epic" OR released > 1990;
```

Output:-

```
Let it go 
I will always love you 
Call me maybe
```

Please help and let me know that my output is correct or wrong? Because it is showing incomplete.

Comment: There's nothing wrong here.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61f7c4/1

Answer (score 0):

Setting your "E" to "e" in "Epic" does make some changes to the query because all the data entries are in lower case but I am having the same problem as you.

I just solved it...
SELECT title FROM songs;
SELECT title FROM songs WHERE mood = "epic" OR released > 1990;

Answer (score -1):

The OR condition requires that any of the conditions (ie: condition1, condition2, condition_n) be must be met for the record to be included in the result set.

```
Bohemian Rhapsody
Let it go
I will survive
I will always love you
Call me maybe
```

[OR fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a151/1)

Whereas the AND condition requires that all of the conditions (ie: condition1, condition2, condition_n) be must be met.

```
Let it go
I will always love you
```

[AND fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4a151/3)

Comment: Call me maybe is neither epic nor happy but a sad indictment of the modern state of music. Besides OR is definitely what's wanted here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.